# AWS sdk for php, how to use waiters to wait for completion of all resources?

Tags: php, promise, aws-sdk

I have problem with following code, as it produce no output in php error log:

```
$proms = [
$ec2->getWaiter('InstanceRunning', ['InstanceIds' => [$ec2_result['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']]])->promise(),
$rds->getWaiter('DBInstanceAvailable', ['DBInstanceIdentifier' => $rds_result['DBInstance']['DBInstanceIdentifier']])->promise(),
];

$all = Promise\all($proms)->then(
function ($results) {
    error_log("Works!");
    error_log(print_r($results[0],true));
    error_log(print_r($results[1],true));
},
function ($results) {
    error_log("Do not work!");
    error_log(print_r($results[0],true));
    error_log(print_r($results[1],true));
}
);
```

Did I provided correct functions to *->then* section?
Is there any documentation for it anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.

1) Needed to make sure that code actually work, as there was small bug in one of the setups, so only part of requests where made successfull.

2) Needed to **increase php script time limit** as it was longer then default 30 seconds.